# Words with friends, endgame regarding blanks?

Tags: words-with-friends

In the end game, if i have no letters left, then my opponent's letters are added up and that total subtracted from my opponent's total, and also added to my total.

What is the value of a blank in this case?

Comment: The value of a blank should always be zero; but having never experienced having it at the end of the game, I can't say definitively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I just ended a game leaving only a blank, and my opponent played their last letter.

The end result was no lost points for me, and no gained points for my opponent. The blank, then, is indeed worth zero points at the end.

Also, i won the match - a risky stance in the high-stakes world of wwf, but everyone knows knowledge is worth the effort!